# GitHub login failure within Visual Studio Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I am using company intranet to login to GitHub within VS Code but it fails with following message:

> Sign in failed: FetchError: request to https://vscode-auth.github.com/token?code=******&state=*****-*****-***** failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

If I remove the company proxy setting, it will show me another failure message:

> Failure to connect with proxy <my company proxy>.

This likely means that although I had removed the proxy from Windows proxy settings, I could still not bypass it because somewhere else it still requires it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get any solution to your problem?